# Google Drive API: search file and get a snippet of the content of the results

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I have a php script that uses the `google/apiclient` from `composer` libraries to search for files on Google Drive.
I know I can get extra data/metadata of the results using `fields` but there is no field like `fullText` that comes with the results and contains either the full text or a snippet of the text where the search query was found.
My goal is to give the end user some context of what the result is and if it really is the file they are looking for.

Has anyone done something like this? Maybe a hidden field?

To give a more visual idea of what I have running:

```
$result = $service->files->listFiles(
  [
    'q' => "fullText contains 'find this on the file content'",
    'supportsAllDrives' => TRUE,
    'includeItemsFromAllDrives' => TRUE,
    'corpora' => 'allDrives',
    'fields' => 'files(id, size, thisFieldContainsTheTextSnippetWhereTheQueryWasFound )'
  ]
);
```

And I want this as a result:

```
 $result = Google\Service\Drive\FileList Object
(
    [collection_key:protected] => files
    [filesType:protected] => Google\Service\Drive\DriveFile
    [filesDataType:protected] => array
    [files] => Array
        (
            [0] => Google\Service\Drive\DriveFile Object
                (
                    [collection_key:protected] => spaces
                    [appProperties] =>
                    [capabilitiesType:protected] => Google\Service\Drive\DriveFileCapabilities
                    [capabilitiesDataType:protected] =>
                    [capabilities] =>
                    [contentHintsType:protected] => Google\Service\Drive\DriveFileContentHints
                    [contentHintsDataType:protected] =>
                    [contentHints] =>
                    [contentRestrictionsType:protected] => Google\Service\Drive\ContentRestriction
                    [contentRestrictionsDataType:protected] => array
                    [contentRestrictions] =>
                    [copyRequiresWriterPermission] =>
                    [createdTime] =>
                    [description] =>
                    [driveId] =>
                    [explicitlyTrashed] =>
                    [exportLinks] =>
                    [fileExtension] =>
                    [folderColorRgb] =>
                    [fullFileExtension] =>
                    [hasAugmentedPermissions] =>
                    [hasThumbnail] =>
                    [headRevisionId] =>
                    [iconLink] =>
                    [id] => hAshID
                    [imageMediaMetadataType:protected] => Google\Service\Drive\DriveFileImageMediaMetadata
                    [imageMediaMetadataDataType:protected] =>
                    [imageMediaMetadata] =>
                    [isAppAuthorized] =>
                    [kind] =>
                    [labelInfoType:protected] => Google\Service\Drive\DriveFileLabelInfo
                    [labelInfoDataType:protected] =>
                    [labelInfo] =>
                    [lastModifyingUserType:protected] => Google\Service\Drive\User
                    [lastModifyingUserDataType:protected] =>
                    [lastModifyingUser] =>
                    [linkShareMetadataType:protected] => Google\Service\Drive\DriveFileLinkShareMetadata
                    [linkShareMetadataDataType:protected] =>
                    [linkShareMetadata] =>
                    [md5Checksum] =>
                    [mimeType] =>
                    [modifiedByMe] =>
                    [modifiedByMeTime] =>
                    [modifiedTime] =>
                    [name] =>
                    [originalFilename] =>
                    [ownedByMe] =>
                    [ownersType:protected] => Google\Service\Drive\User
                    [ownersDataType:protected] => array
                    [owners] =>
                    [parents] =>
                    [permissionIds] =>
                    [permissionsType:protected] => Google\Service\Drive\Permission
                    [permissionsDataType:protected] => array
                    [permissions] =>
                    [properties] =>
                    [quotaBytesUsed] =>
                    [resourceKey] =>
                    [sha1Checksum] =>
                    [sha256Checksum] =>
                    [shared] =>
                    [sharedWithMeTime] =>
                    [sharingUserType:protected] => Google\Service\Drive\User
                    [sharingUserDataType:protected] =>
                    [sharingUser] =>
                    [shortcutDetailsType:protected] => Google\Service\Drive\DriveFileShortcutDetails
                    [shortcutDetailsDataType:protected] =>
                    [shortcutDetails] =>
                    [size] => fileSize
                    [spaces] =>
                    [starred] =>
                    [teamDriveId] =>
                    [thumbnailLink] =>
                    [thumbnailVersion] =>
                    [trashed] =>
                    [trashedTime] =>
                    [trashingUserType:protected] => Google\Service\Drive\User
                    [trashingUserDataType:protected] =>
                    [trashingUser] =>
                    [version] =>
                    [videoMediaMetadataType:protected] => Google\Service\Drive\DriveFileVideoMediaMetadata
                    [videoMediaMetadataDataType:protected] =>
                    [videoMediaMetadata] =>
                    [viewedByMe] =>
                    [viewedByMeTime] =>
                    [viewersCanCopyContent] =>
                    [webContentLink] =>
                    [webViewLink] =>
                    [writersCanShare] =>
                    [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [modelData:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [processed:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )
              >>>>> [thisFieldContainsTheTextSnippetWhereTheQueryWasFound] => '...as i was broswing the website to find this on the file content, i was forced to ask about on st...'  <<<<<

                )
        (
            [1] => Google\Service\Drive\DriveFile Object
                (
... cut to avoid repeating unnecessary stuff ...
                    [id] => AnotherhAshID
... cut to avoid repeating unnecessary stuff ...
              >>>>> [thisFieldContainsTheTextSnippetWhereTheQueryWasFound] => '...this file has the text "find this on the file content", but just as an example and it is not what I am looking for...'  <<<<<

                )

        )

    [incompleteSearch] =>
    [kind] =>
    [nextPageToken] =>
    [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [modelData:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [processed:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? How is this problem related to Composer?

Comment: @NicoHaase I am now going to print all the methods on the File object and see if maybe I'm missing something. I have also checked the api docs but they talk more about the resource endpoint (url) than the resource objects themselves (the file found). Not sure if this is "composer related problem", I used the tag because I am using the libraries that composer provides to connect to google apis. Maybe I used the tag or expresed myself wrong?

Comment: @Vanscot: yes, you're using the `composer` tag wrong, as this is not a question about composer itself. You just used composer to pull in your dependencies. Instead you should (or could) [edit] your question and put in the concrete version of the google api-client library (compare `composer show`) so you have it documented and it is clear about which version you ask (libraries can change over time).

Comment: I see, I'll check the google api-client library version and add the proper tag to the post. I've also removed the composer tag too.